# How to get the corresponding values of the latest date in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vlookup

I have this values in my excel:

```
      A      B       C        D             
  StaffId  FSales  ESales    Date  
      1     100     500     23-Jan-13
      1     50      170     25-Jan-13
      1     70      230     26-Jan-13
      2     100     300     25-Jan-13  
      2     130     200     27-Jan-13
```

Outcome wanted:

```
      A      B       C        D             
  StaffId  FSales  ESales    Date  
      1     100     500     23-Jan-13 10:00:00AM
      1     50      170     25-Jan-13 11:00:00AM
      1     70      230     26-Jan-13 11:30:00AM
      2     100     300     25-Jan-13 03:00:00PM 
      2     130     200     27-Jan-13 02:00:00PM
      3     100     200     29-Jan-13 01:01:00PM
      3     90      209     29-Jan-13 01:00:00PM


      A      B       C        D             
  StaffId  FSales  ESales    Date 
      1      70      230     26-Jan-13 11:30:00AM
      2      130     200     27-Jan-13 02:00:00PM
      3      100     200     29-Jan-13 01:01:00PM
```

Lets say dates are jumbled up and not arranged in any order. How can i get the latest date Fsales and ESales for each staff?
Meaning getting 70 230 for staffid 1 and 130 200 for staffid 2. 
Help needed please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the second list with the unique staff ID in Sheet2 and the original list in Sheet1, starting in row 2, enter the following formula:

FSales max in Sheet2!B2: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$D:$D*(Sheet1!$A:$A=A2)),(Sheet1!$D:$D*(Sheet1!$A:$A=A2)),0))`

ESales max in Sheet2!C2: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$D:$D*(Sheet1!$A:$A=A2)),(Sheet1!$D:$D*(Sheet1!$A:$A=A2)),0))`

Both formulas are array-formulas, i.e. enter them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Its return me #NUM! in the cell where i put the value...Sorry but i am very new to such high level excel. I edit my OP, mind helping me in greater details?Thanks thanks

Comment: I updated the formulas to reflect that the output table is on a different worksheet. Also, make sure that you enter the array formula correctly - if done correctly, you'll see these `{}` brackets around the formula...